# Pusher API not working on production server

Tags: python, flask, pusher

I am using python flask, and pusher API for live messaging on my website.
Everything works as expected in development flask server, but the trouble starts when I switch to gunicorn and nginx live servers.
When I trigger pusher event I get an error 500.
Maybe I have to configure something in my nginx.conf file?

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/đir`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 172.104.228.152;

        location /static {
                alias /home/marko/Đir/đir/static;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}.
```

This is the error message:

```
[2020-02-03 17:00:25,938] ERROR in app: Exception on /objave [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/marko/Đir/đir/rute.py", line 30, in dekorator
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/marko/Đir/đir/rute.py", line 143, in objave
    pusher_client.trigger('objava-kanal', 'nova-objava', {'sport': objava.sport, 'mjesto': objava.mjesto, 'datum': datum, 'sat': sat, 'id': objava.id, 'broj': len(o>  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pusher/pusher.py", line 118, in trigger
    channels, event_name, data, socket_id)
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pusher/http.py", line 31, in __call__
    return self.client.http.send_request(self.make_request(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pusher/requests.py", line 44, in send_request
    **self.options)
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout                                                                                                                                                    File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen                                                     chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 394, in connect
    ssl_context=context,
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 336, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs, ca_cert_dir)
  File "/home/marko/\udcc4\udc90ir/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 450, in load_verify_locations
    cafile = cafile.encode("utf-8")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 12-13: surrogates not allowed
```

**Edit**:
'routes.py'

```
pusher_client = pusher.Pusher(
  app_id='930370',
  key='43251c740e8c7fdc4747',
  secret='6cc68633eec00ebf9b9d',
  cluster='eu',
  ssl=True
)

@app.route("/objave", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@potrebna_prijava
def objave():
    #obrazac za novi događaj
    obrazac = ObjavaObrazac()
    #obrazac za filter događaja
    _filter = Filter()

    if obrazac.validate_on_submit():
        datum = datetime.strptime(obrazac.datum.data, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
        objava = Objava(sport=obrazac.sport.data.capitalize(), mjesto=obrazac.mjesto.data.capitalize(), datum=datum, opis=obrazac.opis.data, korisnik_id=session["korisnik_id"])
        db.session.add(objava)
        db.session.commit()
        datum = objava.datum.strftime("%a, %d.").capitalize()
        sat = objava.datum.strftime("%H:%M")
        #pusher trigger
        pusher_client.trigger('objava-kanal', 'nova-objava', {'sport': objava.sport, 'mjesto': objava.mjesto, 'datum': datum, 'sat': sat, 'id': objava.id, 'broj': len(objava.sudionici)})
        flash('Kreirano', 'dobro')
        return redirect(url_for('objave'))

    if _filter.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('objave', mjesto_filter=_filter.f_mjesto.data, sport_filter=_filter.f_sport.data))
    objave = selektiraj()
    #slika korisnika
    avatar = Korisnik.query.get(session.get("korisnik_id")).avatar
    return render_template("objave.html", obrazac=obrazac, objave=objave, avatar=avatar, filter=_filter)
```

P.S.
translations: objava = post, objave = posts, obrazac = form

Comment: huumm, your error is in flask, not in nginx, are using accent (à,ó,í) or some special character(ç,ö)? witch is the python version on debug server and release server(normally the python 2 have some trouble with accent and special characters)

Comment: Yes I’m using character “đ”, app and package folder name is called đir, but I don’t use it in pusher trigger (as far as I know). Everything works when I run with flask run, but doesn’t work with gunicorn and nginx. Python verison is 3 (3.7 I belive)

Comment: Could you share the snippet for the `/objave` route? It's an error with Flask and not with Nginx or Gunicorn. Also, if you could share the data that you are trying to send to that endpoint

Comment: Hy, I added it in the edit (route for objave). Btw. pusher doesn't work in other routes either, I just don't get an error because there I used try:, except:

Comment: Does `pusher_client.trigger` accept JSON string or a dict?

Comment: Docs for pusher_client.trigger.

https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-python/blob/master/README.md#triggering-events

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by setting pusher ssl = False.
It is really strange solution, nowhere to be sad in documentation or error log.